# How to convert this jquery code into javascript DOM code?

Tags: javascript, dom

Hi everyone I was just wondering if anyone know how to convert this css/jquery code into javascript DOM code?

I started coding my entire code using javascript DOM for a project but then I found this code which will make the background image move upwards in an infinite loop.

I just need some help in figuring out how to convert the code since I know nothing about jquery.

```js
    $(function(){
            var x = 0;
            setInterval(function(){
                $('body').css('background-position','0'+--x + 'px');
            }, 10);
    })
```

```css
    html,body {    height: 100%; overflow: hidden;}
    body {
        background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1900/1200/');
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
```

```
html,body {    height: 100%; overflow: hidden;}
body {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1900/1200/');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

$(function(){
        var x = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            $('body').css('background-position','0'+--x + 'px');
        }, 10);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('body')` selects the body element; `.css(prop, value)` sets the CSS property `prop` to `value`. With the plain DOM API, you can get the body using `document.body` and assign styles by assigning to properties on the element’s `style`, noting that hyphenated-names become camelCase.

```
var x = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    document.body.style.backgroundPosition = '0 ' + --x + 'px';
}, 10);
```

Comment: If you want to avoid the camelisation, you can also do `elem.style[prop] = ...`